# Playing video including sound with autoplay (HTML5)

Tags: html5-video, autoplay

Today I tried to play a video including sound automatically as soon as the site loads.
Nothing worked for me.
After a little research I saw on the "w3schools" website

> Note: Chromium browsers do not allow autoplay in most cases. However, muted autoplay is always allowed.

For me if w3schools writing this, it's probably true.
But in the example on their site it works, [w3schools video player](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video)
Change the "controls" to autoplay and its work including sound.
Why does it work for them?

Comment: FYI, MDN is a much better JS learning source than W3Schools. From this [guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Autoplay_guide#autoplay_availability), I think it's because the "run" button counts as an interaction with the page, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: @DanyMaor What kind of site needs sound on page loading? Is it a Rick-Roll?

Comment: the site is a game